# str_detect producing vector related errors in R code (which previously worked) since update 1.5.0

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'm trying to do some simple str_detects as follows:

`index1 <- str_detect(colnames(DataFrame), paste0("^", name_))`

also, `name_` is just a character string so `paste0("^", name_))` is of length 1.
which yields the following error:

`Error in` stop_vctrs()`: ! Input must be a vector, not an environment.`

When I check rlang::last_error() I get:
`Backtrace:

1. stringr::str_detect(colnames(DataFrame), paste0("^", name_))
2. vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(`<env>`), "")
3. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)`

I know that in this instance I could use the base R alternative:
`grep(paste0("^", name_), colanmes(DataFrame))`

but the issue is that I have many long scripts which feature str_detect many times...

I'd like to understand the ways around this new error so that I can best fix all these instances in my code, thank you.

I have read the update on Stringr 1.5.0 written by Hadley about the stricter vector definitions which have been implemented in tidyverse but I still pose my question

EDIT: uninstallation and reinstallation of R/studio/tools fixed the issue

Comment: What if you escape the `^`, which is a regex metacharacter, like so: `\\^`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I'm intending to anchor the pattern to the start of the string with ^ to avoid some unintended matches that I would otherwise get. Tried it anyway and error persists.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce it with stringr 1.5.0 & stringi 1.7.12, `name_ <- "ge"; stringr::str_detect(colnames(mtcars), paste0("^", name_))` evaluates just fine.

Comment: "`name_` is just a character string" - then why is it not in quote marks? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Change the names of columns?

Comment: Can you provide a reprex for us to test? All previous posts on this topic I can find either involved a typo (passing an enviroment to the function) or were fixed by a reinstall of Rstudio + applicable packages.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen i am performing a reinstall and will get back to you on the result of such, thank you